# Cascading Logic in Excel (Drop down menu)

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

I need help 
Table 1:

- Column 1 / Column 2
- AA   / xx
- BB / yy
- CC / zz
- DD / xx

Table 2 has a column for Table 1 where the values will be xx, yy, or zz.

Table 3 has a column for Table 1 where the values will be AA, BB, CC, or DD based on the data in Table 2.

Essentially, I need to limit the options of Table 3 based on what is in Table 2.
For example, if Table 2 has yy, that value in table 3 should only have a dropdown menu with BB included. However, if Table 2 has xx, the dropdown in Table 3 should have options for AA and DD.

Table 2 and Table 3 are in the same order so no need to account for how to map it. I just need help with the cascading logic. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html

Comment: use indirect formula